# jquery show hide issue with non block elements

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, css

I am trying to show/hide a users twitter feed when the icon is clicked on. The issue is that my markup looks like this:

```
<a href="#"><img src='images/twitter.png' id='twitterImg' /></a>
<span id='twitter_msg'><? include('PHP/twitterJSON.php'); ?></span>
```

And my jquery uses the slideToggle()

```
$('#twitterImg').click(function() {
$('#twitter_msg').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Which works fine but the `<img>` and the `<span>` are displayed inline and floated left. When I click on the img it will toggle the `<span>` but seems to turn it into a block level element or something and it drops down onto the next line.

What I really want to achieve is to float them right and have the `<span>` push the `<img>` left when it appears and then collapse back again when its hidden.

Comment: We'll need the CSS in this case as well, can you update the question with it?

Comment: literally the only relevant piece of css is applied to the container div for the above two lines (float: left;)
should I just be applying a float to the span as well

Comment: Honestly, I would use a fade in this case, re-flowing the document is rarely a good idea if it can be avoided, is that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to have to assume that jquery does change it to a block level element before applying the effect to it. I have rectified this by floating the img and the span separately, although I don't know whether anyone has some other solutions.

Comment: It's not something you have to assume. That's what jQuery does for show (display:block) and hide (display:none), and for all effects. Show/hide is easier to get around, but I've no idea for animations. You might try installing firebug if you're on FF so you can see the animation/jQuery happen in real time.